# How to get html from node or HTMLElement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, parsing, dom

I'm trying to convert the pure html of a Node or HTMLElement to string but i can't seem to get the right result as shown in the console. That means just the html element, not it's child elements...

**CODE**

```
function eventData(e){
    return {
        'sender': e.srcElement || e.target,
        'event': e || window.event,
    };
};

$(document).ready(function(e){
    var $elm = $("<input class='test' data-type='text only'/>").attr({'type':'button','value':'Test'});
    $elm.appendTo('#target');
    $elm.click(function(e) { alert(eventData(e).sender.value); });
    $('#asHTML').text($elm[0].toString());

    //Console is the best way to display a node object;
    //Open your console to see the result;
    console.log($elm[0]);
});
```

I'm just wondering if any one of you has successfully done this!

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/0xfwLfwj/1/

**EDIT**
Updated fiddle with better explanation: http://jsfiddle.net/ttoom9hc/10/

Comment: Why do you use `eventData`? jQuery fixes IE problems for you.

Comment: Try `$elm[0].innerHTML` or `$elm[0].outerHTML` to get the html of an `HTMLElement` instance. Not sure what you want to do in case of `Node` instances.

Comment: maybe `this.get(0);`

Comment: Doing this works, but it also reads it's child elements. I only need the actual HTML element. Maybe there's a way to avoid the child elements?

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you want to display -

```
<input class="test" data-type="text only" type="button" value="Test">
```

Then this is the piece of code for it -

```
$('#asHTML').text($elm[0].outerHTML);
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ttoom9hc/)

Comment: It seems that my question missed a line. I only need the string from the current element, not it's child elements.

Comment: so what output you want to achieve?

Comment: I've updated this post to better explain the desired output./

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
$elm.html()
```

That should give you the HTML of that element as a string.
http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: Doing this works, but it also reads it's child elements. I only need the actual HTML element. Maybe there's a way to avoid the child elements?